# How would I go about deleting a single item in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

How would I go about deleting just a single item?

Provided I know the 'name' value ("To add") but I don't know the item ID value (-M0qUq...).

The following code works to delete the item, but I want to make it dynamic and not have to hardcode in the ID value.

```
handleRemove = (item) => {

    db.ref('/items/-M0qUPNnHRbZAb1R3690/').remove();
  }
```

[image: Screenshot of my Firebase Realtime Database]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
let query = db.ref('items').orderByChild("name").equalTo("To add");
db.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((subSnapshot) => {
    let key = subSnapshot.key;
    db.ref('items').child(key).remove();
 });
});
```

First add a query `equalTo`, then iterate inside the returned result to be able to retrieve the `key` and then use `remove()` to delete.

Comment: No this did not work, unfortunately. It deleted the all of the "items" instead of just a single one. I ended up modifying your method and using the index of the 'item' I wanted to delete. 
        `itemsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        
      snapshot.forEach((subSnapshot) => {
        
        var key = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[index];
        let random = itemsRef.child(key)
        
        itemsRef.child(key).remove();
        
      });
    });`